# Click event doesn't work on firefox for small objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I have drawn two rectangles using path in svg. Click event works fine on large rectangle, but the same doesn't works on small rectangle.

Image for bigger rectangle:

[image]

Here is my code snippet:
`

```
<svg id="svgDocument" style="overflow: hidden; z-index: 0; float: left; position: relative; height: 600px; width: 900px;
 margin-top: 0px; margin-left: 0px;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"> 
<g id="rootGroup" transform="scale(8192) translate(-117.71870117262006, -202.511474609375)">
<path id="data" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M117.7315673828125,202.5401611328125,117.7315673828125,202.5142822265625,
117.763427734375,202.5142822265625,117.763427734375,202.5401611328125Z" fill="Blue" stroke-width="0.0006103515625" stroke="red" class="mapShape" 
nodeValue="Blue"/>
<path id="data1" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M117.7685546875,202.54638671874997,117.7685546875,202.54309082031253,117.7730712890625,
202.54309082031253,117.7730712890625,202.54638671874997Z" fill="Blue" stroke-width="0.0006103515625" stroke="red" class="mapShape" nodeValue="Blue"/>
</g>
</svg>
<script>
 document.getElementById('data').addEventListener('click', function (e){
     alert('Event triggered for big rect');
  });
document.getElementById('data1').addEventListener('click', function (e){
      alert('Event triggered for small rect');
  });
</script>
```

Here is my fiddle link:[Sample](https://jsfiddle.net/n5rgx56r/4/)

I have tried using mouseup, mousedown, mousemove, mouseenter events, but none of them works for small rectangle.

Kindly help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Have you tried drawing things closer to the scale you're actually going to use i.e. removing the transform="scale(8192) translate(-117.71870117262006, -202.511474609375)" and fixing the contents appropriately.

Comment: I've just had a look and I have a hunch that in Firefox the clicks are caught by the parent `<svg>`. E.g. Try right clicking an inspecting the element, it will select the parent svg, instead of the child. I'm not sure why this is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

If you try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(this).on('click', function(e){
  alert($(e.target).attr('id'));
 });
});
```

Paths you have given are wrong:

```
<svg id="svgDocument" style="overflow: hidden; z-index: 0; float: left; position: relative; height: 600px; width: 900px;
 margin-top: 0px; margin-left: 0px;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"> 
<g id="rootGroup">
<path id="data" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" fill="Blue" stroke-width="0.0006103515625" stroke="red" class="mapShape" 
nodeValue="Blue"/>
</g>

<g id="g2">
<path id="data1" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M250 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" fill="Red" stroke-width="0.0006103515625" stroke="red" class="mapShape" nodeValue="Blue"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

This selects correct ID on 'click' event.

jsfiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/k4p6suy4/1/